# Unable to see the Article Management tab in Salesforce

Tags: knowledge

Even though I have enabled the **knowledge User** I don't see the `Article Management` option. Why?

> ### [Build Your Knowledge Base](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=knowledge_setup.htm&type=0)
>
> To enable Salesforce Knowledge, from Setup, enter Knowledge in the Quick Find box, then select Knowledge Settings. Confirm that you want to enable Salesforce Knowledge and click Enable Knowledge. If your org doesn't have an article type, a default article type is created.

[image: Knowledge Settings Part 1]

---

[image: Language Settings Part 2]

**UPDATED UPDATED**

[image]

**I have already made the default On  setting**

[image]

**[image: Also I dont see any where Article management tab anywhere]**

Comment: if you click on all tabs, do you see knowledge there?

Comment: Yes I see knowledge. But I dont see article Management !! Why ???

Comment: if you add this after your .com/ in the url  knowledge/publishing/knowledgePublishingHome.apexp

Comment: Yes I can see My Draft Article Page. I wonder why Article Management tab not coming?

Comment: check the following KB https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=000005402&language=en_US&type=1

Comment: Yes I already went through link. Everything looks good. Not sure whats the problem is ?

Comment: if you create an App, and select knowledge and or article management from the available tabs? make this app available for your profile only, in order to test

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/57785/discussion-between-glls-and-user4567570).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try creating a new App (for example, knowledge app), go through the creation wizards, and when it comes to selecting available tabs, look for Knowledge and Article Management. Make sure the App is available to System administrators only so you can test.[image]

[image]

It is possible that the tab is there and you might have just missed it for some reason (for example, too many tabs):
[image]

Otherwise, take a look at [this](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=000005402&language=en_US&type=1) knowledge article.

> How do I configure the Articles and Article Management tabs to appear?

Make sure the profile has the article management tab settings set to Default On:[image]

Comment: Thnx, I my current App I can see that option 'Article Management', but why that tab is not seeing?

Comment: Could be that the  tab was configured to hidden? in the last screenshot i set to default on , however, this does not impede you to access the tab using the url shortcut i sent you. @user4567570 make sure to accept the answer once this is resolved. Cheers

Comment: Thanx for this. I updated my posts. I almost spent 4 hours, and checked almost all possible options, but still struggling to get the Aritcle Management anywhere !!